# Why my function in my program still running without including my library header file

Tags: c, header, dev-c++

My project have 3 file, which are main.c , and 2 files for my library (increase.h and increase.c). In my main.c these is a function I have writen in increase.c, when i delete #include "increase.h" in main, I expected the program to crash but somehow it still gave my correct answer.

Here is  my program

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int a =9,b= 5;
   printf("%d",inc(a));
  
}
```

increas.h

```
#ifndef INCREAS_H_INCLUDED
#define INCREAS_H_INCLUDED

int inc(int a);

#endif
```

increas.c

```
int inc(int a)
{
    return a+1;
}
```

Comment: Please include all code, input, and output directly in the question *as text*, not a picture of text and not a link to a picture of text.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Then read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As *part* of your "problem", Dev-C++ is old and outdated and not under active development. It comes with a very old compiler, that defaults to a very old version of the C specification. And that is relevant to your problem, because in very old C you don't have to declare functions before calling them. It was disallowed in later version of the C standard (the C99 standard, which is still very old now). There are other free IDE's and editors that are much better, and that comes with or can be used with modern compilers that uses modern standards.

Comment: ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings. With gcc, you could use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expected the program to crash but somehow it still gave my correct
> answer.

because you do not have the function prototype the compiler is using the implict return and parameters type which is `int`. As your function returns `int` and takes `int` parameter - it works fine.

Try to pass and return the pointer to int or double and your program will invoke undefined behaviour and most likely to stop working correctly.

```
double inc(double a)
{
    return a+1.0;
}
```

```
int main()
{
   double a =9,b= 5;
   printf("%d",inc(a));
  
}
```

Comment: Could you explain for me why the complier knows what inc() function is without include increas.h

Comment: @Mr.Nothing because it is as it is (C standard). No prototype - `int` is implicit type for return type and parameters